# Mouse location relative to a div? or div location relative to the viewing window?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm making a team members page,  I want to make the pictures of the people look at where the mouse is.  To do this I need to know where the mouse is in relation to the div that the image is in.

I know how to find the location of the mouse in the viewing window using .mousemove(function(e) .  but I don't know how to get the location of the div with respect to the viewing window.  Or if I could just find the mouse location with respect to the div it would cut out the middle man.

Once I can get the coordinates,  I should be able to swap out the images depending on the mouse location with if statements.

Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Evuv2/108/   replace the a with eye :)

Comment: I used that example when trying originally.  unfortunately it only give the mouse position relative to the viewing window.  and based on the size of the browser window the div is not at the same absolute position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made a fully working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zK7p6/1/

Comment: Thanks! thats exactly what I was trying to do :)